# How to create particular month and/or date sequence "n" number of times

Tags: r, date, seq, rep

I am trying to create a sequence of months 
from Jan- Dec 3 times. ie.
Jan 
Feb
Mar
.
.
.
.
Dec
Jan
Feb
Mar
.
.
.
.
Dec
Jan
Feb
Mar
.
.
.
.
Dec

I tried this code

```
rep(c("Jan","Feb","Mar","Apr","May","Jun","Jul","Aug","Sept","Oct","Nov","Dec"),each=3)
```

but it generates  result like this

```
[1] "Jan"  "Jan"  "Jan"  "Feb"  "Feb"  "Feb"  "Mar"  "Mar"  "Mar"  "Apr"  "Apr"  "Apr" 
[13] "May"  "May"  "May"  "Jun"  "Jun"  "Jun"  "Jul"  "Jul"  "Jul"  "Aug"  "Aug"  "Aug" 
[25] "Sept" "Sept" "Sept" "Oct"  "Oct"  "Oct"  "Nov"  "Nov"  "Nov"  "Dec"  "Dec"  "Dec"
```

but I want Jan Feb Mar....Dec Jan Feb Mar.....Dec Jan Feb Mar...Dec

Thanks
Harshad

Comment: try `rep(c("Jan","Feb","Mar","Apr","May","Jun","Jul","Aug","Sept","Oct","Nov","Dec"),3)`

Comment: use `times=` in rep.  Also you can make it compact `rep(month.abb, 3)`

Answer (score 9):

We can use `month.abb` instead of `c('Jan', 'Feb')`, etc..

```
 rep(month.abb, 3)
```

For full month name

```
 rep(month.name, 3)
```

Comment: Good to see the use of internal vectors.

Comment: Thanks...yeah neat and clean way it is.

Answer (score 2):

Use `times=3`

```
rep(c("Jan","Feb","Mar","Apr","May","Jun","Jul","Aug","Sept","Oct","Nov","Dec"),times=3)
#  [1] "Jan"  "Feb"  "Mar"  "Apr"  "May"  "Jun"  "Jul"  "Aug"  "Sept" "Oct"  "Nov"  "Dec"  "Jan" 
# [14] "Feb"  "Mar"  "Apr"  "May"  "Jun"  "Jul"  "Aug"  "Sept" "Oct"  "Nov"  "Dec"  "Jan"  "Feb" 
# [27] "Mar"  "Apr"  "May"  "Jun"  "Jul"  "Aug"  "Sept" "Oct"  "Nov"  "Dec"
```